# Command invalid: run always ask to create a project

Tags: aurelia

I have a project about 4 months and suddenly the aurelia's CLI commands are not working.

When I try to execute au run --watch I receive a message with options to create a new project under the path.

I have already tried to uninstall and reinstall the aurelia CLI, It's not work.

The last thing I have done was to execute a git clean -xdf

I think that could be something on my project. Someone could help me?

**ANSWER**

After some attempts I fixed the problem:

1) I reinstall Git and Node;

2) I have deleted all the files under the `\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache` path;

3) I have checked if the Git and Node were in the PATH of environment variables;

4) I run the `npm install` command;

Answer (score 4):

Is `aurelia-cli` included in the `devDependencies` of the project and also installed globally?

First, install globally:

- `npm i -g aurelia-cli`

Then, in the project directory, install & save to `devDependencies`:

- `npm i --save-dev aurelia-cli`

You should then be able to run `au` in the project directory and see that the `build` and `run` commands are now available.

Note that you'll also need to install the necessary `gulp` dependencies required by the tasks in your project `devDependencies`.

---

**EDIT**: See [`aurelia/cli/issues/485`](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/485) which confirms that installing `aurelia-cli` as a local dependency fixes this issue.